# How to find the SVG path for Smiley Face happy neutral unhappy

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have Smiley Face happy .SVG path but i am unable to find the neutral unhappy .SVG path.

**Below is the code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Santosh Bokefode SVG Sample</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
 <h2>Smiley Face</h2>
 <svg height="200" width="600" xmlns=http://www.w3.org/2000/svg>
  <circle id="yellowcircle" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="yellow"/>
  <circle id="blackcircle" cx="30" cy="30" r="10" fill="black"/>
  <circle id="blackcircle" cx="70" cy="30" r="10" fill="black"/>
  <ellipse id="blackellipse" cx="50" cy="75" rx="20" ry="8" fill="black"/>
  <ellipse id="yellowellipse" cx="50" cy="73" rx="20" ry="8" fill="yellow"/>
  <g transform='translate(15,65)'>
   <path d="M0,0 A40,40 10 0,0 65,0" fill=none stroke=black stroke-width=5 />  
  </g>
 </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The smileys present in this question and Ivan's answer are somewhat creepy

Comment: @NickA agree, but actually I don't get the question

Comment: Why is question tagged by *javascript*? Do you want to animate your smile or only get `d` attribute values of the `<path>` for neutral and unhappy face?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wants this result?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Santosh Bokefode SVG Sample</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
 <h2>Smiley Face</h2>
 <svg height="200" width="600" xmlns=http://www.w3.org/2000/svg>
  <circle id="yellowcircle" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="yellow"/>
  <circle id="blackcircle" cx="30" cy="30" r="10" fill="black"/>
  <circle id="blackcircle" cx="70" cy="30" r="10" fill="black"/>
  
  <g transform="translate(85,85) rotate(180)">
  <path d="M0,0 A40,40 10 0,0 65,0" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"></path>  
 </g>
 </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share path for neutral face also

Comment: @santosh_b88 replace `g` tag  <g transform="translate(19,70)">
  <path d="M0,0 65,0" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"></path>  
 </g>